# JavaScript/TypeScript how to build OffsetDateTime like in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, datetimeoffset, offsetdatetime

I am very new to java script, how to build offset date time in javascript, which I use to use to call and API which gets date time in string.

`2020-08-27T22:54:36.922Z -> Like this in JavaScript/TypeScript`

The samething in Java i will do something like this.

`OffsetDateTime.now().toString()`

Please let me know. The frontend is Javascript and I am planning to get offset date as string in the API and process that in the Java Handler in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `toISOString()` method on `Date`. You would call that on a freshly created `new Date()` instance that initializes to the current time.

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
```

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 0):

To get the offset in JavaScript:

var now = new Date();
var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset();

You can do math from there for your specific implementation (i.e./ 60).